# Table Cell loop produces undefined index erroneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, indexing

```
$('#process').click(function() {
    var char_matrix = [];
    $('#char_input tr').each(function(e) {
        $(this).children('td').each(function() {
            var a = $(this).css('background-color').replace(/\D+/g, '');
            if (a === '2551650') {
                char_matrix[e] += "0";
            } else {
                char_matrix[e] += "1";
            }//END IF
        });//END EACH
        alert(char_matrix[e]);
    });//END EACH
});//END FUNC
```

This code loops through each table row, and each row cell to create an array of 1's and 0's.  Each index of the array is a different row, and each index is composed of a series 1's and 0's indicating background color status of each row.  Expected output is something like:

```
10101010
10101010
10101010
10101010
10101010
10101010
10101010
10101010
```

Actual output is:

```
undefined10101010
undefined10101010
undefined10101010
undefined10101010
undefined10101010
undefined10101010
undefined10101010
undefined10101010
```

I have no idea what is causing each row to have undefined at the beginning, and it is quite annoying.  The undefined index is actually added to the array, in addition to the correct 8 binary values.  I have tried defining char_matrix as a global and local variable to no avail.

I also realize I can use straight Javascript, but that is not an option for me on this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this line

```
$('#char_input tr').each(function(e) {
```

add this line

```
  char_matrix[e] = ""
```

Otherwise `char_matrix[e]` is initially undefined. This is consistent with your results since

```
undefined + "1" === "undefined1"
```